# Instantiate a Raku class, and update an instance variable in the constructor

Tags: raku

I seem to be having difficulty understanding how to correctly work with classes in Raku.

I am trying to create a 'Database' class that I will use throughout my cro application. However I don't seem to understand how to deal with setting instance variables at object construction (BUILD?) time.

The class below shows an example of the problem I am having when calling it with:

Calling:

```
my $db = Database.new(dsn => 'update me!');
say "what value is foo: " ~ $db.what-is-foo(); # prints "what value is foo: 0" but expecting 123
```

My Class:

```
use DB::Pg;

class Database {
    has Str    $.dsn is required;
    has DB::Pg $!dbh = Nil;
    has Int    $!foo = 0;

    method new (:$dsn) {
        my $dbh = DB::Pg.new(conninfo => :$dsn);
        my $foo = 123;
        return self.bless(:$dsn, dbh => $dbh, foo => $foo);
    }

    method what-is-foo() {
        return $!foo;
    }
}
```

So in my class constructor I would like to pass in a named arg for the database dsn.
In the new method I plan to connect, and set an instance variable to the connection handle.

In this example I am using a simple integer (foo) as a test.

So far I have found [the docs here](https://docs.raku.org/language/classtut) to not include an example of this type of pattern, except pehaps:

```
use DB::Pg;

class Database {
    has Str    $.dsn is required;
    has DB::Pg $!dbh = Nil;
    has Int    $!foo = 0;

    submethod BUILD(:$dsn) {
        $!dbh = DB::Pg.new(conninfo => :$dsn);
        $!foo = 123;
    }

    method what-is-foo() {
        return $!foo;
    }
}
```

But that gives me:

```
The attribute '$!dsn' is required, but you did not provide a value for it.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Only attributes with public accessors (that is, the `.` twigil) are set automatically with `bless`.

You have two ways to handle this.  You can set them at `TWEAK` or `BUILD`, or you can add the attribute `is built` to the attribute to have this done automatically for you. The attribute `is built` is probably the easiest in this case, just say `has Int $!foo is built = 0`.  But it's worth expanding on the other options:

If you include a `BUILD` method, you are responsible for all of the set up on your own.  This means both public *and* private attributes.  But you can make your life easier by smartly naming the parameters:

```
method BUILD (:$!dsn, :$!dbh, :$!foo) { }
```

That's actually it.  The signature binds the incoming values to `$!dsn`, etc., which of course sets them for the whole object instance.  Of course, you can do fancier things here too.  In any case, after `BUILD`, there are some additional checks done.  (1) if you don't set `$!dsn`, because you have `is required`, there will be an error. (2) if you don't ultimately set `$!foo` or `$!dbh`, they will receive their default value.

With `TWEAK`, you get passed the same arguments as you would with `BUILD`, but all initial set up is done (BUILD or the auto-binding to public attributes, and all default values, plus guarantee that required values are there).  You just get a chance to do some last second adjustments.

Comment: That's an excellent answer and explains a lot. Thankyou! In this case I went down the is built route. But I have a better understanding which leads to be believe I will undoubtable use TWEAK at some time in the near future

Comment: I think there is a push to update the docs to use TWEAK more than BUILD. The idea being that 9 times out of 10 it's want you want. And of that other time you probably want BUILD and THEN you might want to write a new method.

Comment: Conversely, if you want an attribute to have an accessor but *not* have it settable at object creation, you can say `has $.foo is built(False)`.  Sadly there is **no** syntactic sugar yet for allowing `has $.foo is !built`.